# libsqlite3.dylib link with CMake

Tags: c++, sqlite, cmake

I'm trying to link libsqlite3.dylib with C++ using CMake, but I keep getting the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_sqlite3_close", referenced from:
      OpnavCamera::~OpnavCamera() in opnav_camera.cpp.o
      OpnavCamera::updateState() in opnav_camera.cpp.o
  "_sqlite3_exec", referenced from:
      select_stmt(char const*) in opnav_camera.cpp.o
  "_sqlite3_open", referenced from:
      OpnavCamera::updateState() in opnav_camera.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [../modules/opnav_camera/_opnav_camera.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [SimCode/CMakeFiles/_opnav_camera.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Looking around online, it looks like I'm not successfully linking the library. I'm new to CMake, so I have no idea what I'm doing.

I've added the following to my CMakelists.txt:

```
#SQLite 3

# Look for the header file.
FIND_PATH(SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES sqlite3.h)

# Look for the library.
FIND_LIBRARY(SQLITE3_LIBRARY NAMES sqlite3.0)

# Handle the QUIETLY and REQUIRED arguments and set SQLITE3_FOUND to TRUE if all listed variables are TRUE.
INCLUDE(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS(SQLITE3 DEFAULT_MSG SQLITE3_LIBRARY SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIR)

# Copy the results to the output variables.
IF(SQLITE3_FOUND)
  SET(SQLITE3_LIBRARIES ${SQLITE3_LIBRARY})
  SET(SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIRS ${SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIR})
  message( " Found ")
ELSE(SQLITE3_FOUND)
  SET(SQLITE3_LIBRARIES)
  SET(SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIRS)
ENDIF(SQLITE3_FOUND)

set (CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,--as-needed")

MARK_AS_ADVANCED(SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIRS SQLITE3_LIBRARIES)
```

CMake is finding the library, but I think I'm just missing a step in how to actually link it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJl6Z.png)

What piece am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake link to external library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774593/cmake-link-to-external-library)

Answer (score 1):

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

It appears you are building a 64 bit application and attempting to link against a 32 bit library. You will need to link against the 64 bit version of the library instead.

Comment: Looks like the library is 64-bit

Comment: Matts-MacBook-Pro:~ Matt$ file /usr/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib
/usr/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib: Mach-O universal binary with 3 architectures: [x86_64: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64] [i386] [x86_64h]
/usr/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib (for architecture x86_64): Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
/usr/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib (for architecture i386): Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386
/usr/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib (for architecture x86_64h): Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64h